# Lookup in std::map

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [STL like container with O(1) performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601060/stl-like-container-with-o1-performance)

I always thought that std::map is a hashed list. In that case shouldn't lookup be O(1). The documentation says it's O(logn). What's an appropriate data structure in STL that mimics a hashed map the best with O(1) insertion and lookup.

Comment: No, it is not a hashed list but it is rather implemented as a tree. At least with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @Benoit: the standard imposes algorithmic complexity on containers.  It basically *has* to be a red-black tree.

Comment: @Andre: Thats what I saw in my linux box - the stl::map is implemented using a red-black tree.

Answer (score 6):

`std::map` is implemented as a binary search tree. So lookups are not O(1). TR1 and C++0x are adding a hash map to the STL called an `unordered_map`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_(C%2B%2B)

Depending on your compiler, you might have `unordered_map` or possible `hash_map` in the STL.

Comment: I looked at the implementation of map in my linux box and it uses a red-black tree and not a binary search tree.

Comment: Just to clarify, although the complexity requirements pretty much limits the implementation to a BST, the standard does not mandate which data structure a container must be implemented as.

Comment: A red-black tree is a binary search tree, with the additional feature that it is balanced.

Comment: @yasourser: A RB tree is an specific type of binary search tree (in particular a variant of *balanced* binary search tree). The standard requires (through the complexity requirements) that `std::map` is implemented as a *balanced binary search tree*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official STL container with constant lookup. However, several library implementations provide a non-standard hash_map container which does O(1) lookups (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html)

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [`std::hash_map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_map_%28C++%29).

Comment: Actually it will be `unordered_map` and `unordered_set` in C++0x unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @MarkB: The link I give states exactly that in the first two lines. Do you feel I should repeat it here?