# Writing your own STL Container

Tags: c++, stl, std

Are there guidelines on how one should write new container which will behave like any `STL` container?

Comment: See the implementations of the existing standard containers, and try to understand them - the functions, the return types, operator overloads, nested types, memory management and all.

Comment: I usually start by copying the member function prototypes of whichever container is closest in concept to what I'm doing, either from msdn, or the standard.  (http://www.cplusplus.com does not have C++11 functions, and www.sgi.com doesn't match)

Comment: @Mooing Duck: you think msdn is closer to the standard than sgi?

Comment: It definitely is. MSDN is current - SGI is pre-Standard

Comment: @Dani: I (mistakenly) thought that the stuff I'd seen at cplusplus.com was from SGI.  I don't know how good SGI is, but they don't have any C++11 stuff I see.  MSDN does.

Comment: See complexity guarantees for the different container types. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181693/what-are-the-complexity-guarantees-of-the-standard-containers

Comment: @MooingDuck: cplusplus.com is notoriously erroneous,there was a thread around here,which pointed out the errors,you may want to lookup for it.

Comment: The best online reference (wrt completeness, correctness and especially usability) is by far cppreference.com. It also explains a ton of language features aside from the library. And it's a wiki, so it should contain less errors than cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Here's a sequence pseudo-container I pieced together from § 23.2.1\4   Note that the `iterator_category` should be one of `std::input_iterator_tag`, `std::output_iterator_tag`,`std::forward_iterator_tag`,`std::bidirectional_iterator_tag`,`std::random_access_iterator_tag`. Also note that the below is *technically* more strict than required, but this is the idea. Note that the vast majority of the "standard" functions are technically optional, due to the awesomeness that is iterators.

```
template <class T, class A = std::allocator<T> >
class X {
public:
    typedef A allocator_type;
    typedef typename A::value_type value_type; 
    typedef typename A::reference reference;
    typedef typename A::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename A::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename A::size_type size_type;

    class iterator { 
    public:
        typedef typename A::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef typename A::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename A::reference reference;
        typedef typename A::pointer pointer;
        typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category; //or another tag

        iterator();
        iterator(const iterator&);
        ~iterator();

        iterator& operator=(const iterator&);
        bool operator==(const iterator&) const;
        bool operator!=(const iterator&) const;
        bool operator<(const iterator&) const; //optional
        bool operator>(const iterator&) const; //optional
        bool operator<=(const iterator&) const; //optional
        bool operator>=(const iterator&) const; //optional

        iterator& operator++();
        iterator operator++(int); //optional
        iterator& operator--(); //optional
        iterator operator--(int); //optional
        iterator& operator+=(size_type); //optional
        iterator operator+(size_type) const; //optional
        friend iterator operator+(size_type, const iterator&); //optional
        iterator& operator-=(size_type); //optional            
        iterator operator-(size_type) const; //optional
        difference_type operator-(iterator) const; //optional

        reference operator*() const;
        pointer operator->() const;
        reference operator[](size_type) const; //optional
    };
    class const_iterator {
    public:
        typedef typename A::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef typename A::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename const A::reference reference;
        typedef typename const A::pointer pointer;
        typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category; //or another tag

        const_iterator ();
        const_iterator (const const_iterator&);
        const_iterator (const iterator&);
        ~const_iterator();

        const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator&);
        bool operator==(const const_iterator&) const;
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator&) const;
        bool operator<(const const_iterator&) const; //optional
        bool operator>(const const_iterator&) const; //optional
        bool operator<=(const const_iterator&) const; //optional
        bool operator>=(const const_iterator&) const; //optional

        const_iterator& operator++();
        const_iterator operator++(int); //optional
        const_iterator& operator--(); //optional
        const_iterator operator--(int); //optional
        const_iterator& operator+=(size_type); //optional
        const_iterator operator+(size_type) const; //optional
        friend const_iterator operator+(size_type, const const_iterator&); //optional
        const_iterator& operator-=(size_type); //optional            
        const_iterator operator-(size_type) const; //optional
        difference_type operator-(const_iterator) const; //optional

        reference operator*() const;
        pointer operator->() const;
        reference operator[](size_type) const; //optional
    };

    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator; //optional
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator; //optional

    X();
    X(const X&);
    ~X();

    X& operator=(const X&);
    bool operator==(const X&) const;
    bool operator!=(const X&) const;
    bool operator<(const X&) const; //optional
    bool operator>(const X&) const; //optional
    bool operator<=(const X&) const; //optional
    bool operator>=(const X&) const; //optional

    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    iterator end();
    const_iterator end() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;
    reverse_iterator rbegin(); //optional
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const; //optional
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const; //optional
    reverse_iterator rend(); //optional
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const; //optional
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const; //optional

    reference front(); //optional
    const_reference front() const; //optional
    reference back(); //optional
    const_reference back() const; //optional
    template<class ...Args>
    void emplace_front(Args&&...); //optional
    template<class ...Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&...); //optional
    void push_front(const T&); //optional
    void push_front(T&&); //optional
    void push_back(const T&); //optional
    void push_back(T&&); //optional
    void pop_front(); //optional
    void pop_back(); //optional
    reference operator[](size_type); //optional
    const_reference operator[](size_type) const; //optional
    reference at(size_type); //optional
    const_reference at(size_type) const; //optional

    template<class ...Args>
    iterator emplace(const_iterator, Args&&...); //optional
    iterator insert(const_iterator, const T&); //optional
    iterator insert(const_iterator, T&&); //optional
    iterator insert(const_iterator, size_type, T&); //optional
    template<class iter>
    iterator insert(const_iterator, iter, iter); //optional
    iterator insert(const_iterator, std::initializer_list<T>); //optional
    iterator erase(const_iterator); //optional
    iterator erase(const_iterator, const_iterator); //optional
    void clear(); //optional
    template<class iter>
    void assign(iter, iter); //optional
    void assign(std::initializer_list<T>); //optional
    void assign(size_type, const T&); //optional

    void swap(X&);
    size_type size() const;
    size_type max_size() const;
    bool empty() const;

    A get_allocator() const; //optional
};
template <class T, class A = std::allocator<T> >
void swap(X<T,A>&, X<T,A>&); //optional
```

Also, whenever I make a container, I test with a class more or less like this:

```
#include <cassert>
struct verify;
class tester {
    friend verify;
    static int livecount;
    const tester* self;
public:
    tester() :self(this) {++livecount;}
    tester(const tester&) :self(this) {++livecount;}
    ~tester() {assert(self==this);--livecount;}
    tester& operator=(const tester& b) {
        assert(self==this && b.self == &b);
        return *this;
    }
    void cfunction() const {assert(self==this);}
    void mfunction() {assert(self==this);}
};
int tester::livecount=0;
struct verify {
    ~verify() {assert(tester::livecount==0);}
}verifier;
```

Make containers of `tester` objects, and call each one's `function()` as you test your container.  Do not make any global `tester` objects.  If your container cheats anywhere, this `tester` class will `assert` and you'll know that you cheated accidentally somewhere.

Comment: This is interesting.  How does your tester work?  There are several parse errors, which are trivial (missing ';') but not sure how that verify destructor works. Oh, you meant `assert(tester::livecount == 0);`.  Mmmmm, still not sure how this tester framework works.  Could you give an example?

Comment: The tester has a single nonstatic member that's a pointer to itself, and the destructor and members are a way to check that no invalid `memcpy` happened. (test isn't foolproof, but it catches some).  The `livecount` is a simple leak detector, to make sure your container called an equal number of constructors and destructors.

Comment: Ok, I see that, but how does that test your iterator?  BTW, I think you meant `verifier` not `varifier`.

Comment: @Adrian No no, you write your container, and then put a bunch of these in the container, and do things with the container, to verify that you didn't accidentally memcpy, and rememebered to call all the destructors.

Comment: may I suggest inheriting the iterator from `std::iterator` from the header `<iterator>`

Comment: I think `size`, `max_size`, `empty`, and `get_allocator` should be const.

Comment: Also I believe the typedefs on the const_iterator should use `const_reference` and `const_pointer` off of `allocator`. I've been using this to implement a full STL styled container... fantastic work by the way!

Comment: @Trevor: I'm pretty sure that's backwards. The allocator should be using these typedefs. The iterator shouldn't know or care about allocators. Actually, allocators shouldn't know about iterators either. I'm curious why you say that's needed.

Comment: I'm just going off your example, inside the const_iterator you wrote: `typedef typename A::reference const_reference;`. This is problematic because it makes all the `const_reference` return a non-const reference. It should at least be `typedef typename A::const_reference const_reference;`... right? I don't know anything about whether or not that typedef should even be there... it's in your example.

Comment: @Trevor: Looking closer, you're right. `reference` and `pointer` were both misnamed and incorrectly const qualified. Fixed.

Answer (score 30):

You will need to read the C++ Standard section about Containers and requirements the C++ Standard imposes for container implementations.

The relevant chapter in C++03 standard is:

**Section 23.1 Container Requirements**

The relevant chapter in C++11 standard is:

**Section 23.2 Container Requirements**

The near-final draft of the C++11 standard is freely available **[here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)**.

You might as well, read some excellent books which will help you understand the requirements from an perspective of user of the container. Two excellent books which struck my mind easily are:

***[Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)*** by *Scott Meyers*  &
***[The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260)*** by *Nicolai Josutils*

Answer (score 9):

Here is a very simplistic implementation of a fake vector, which is basically a wrapper around `std::vector` and has its own (but real) iterator, which mimics the STL iterator. Again, the iterator is very simplistic, skipping over many concepts like `const_iterator`, validity checks etc.

Code is runnable out of the box.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct It
{
    std::vector<T>& vec_;
    int pointer_;

    It(std::vector<T>& vec) : vec_{vec}, pointer_{0} {}

    It(std::vector<T>& vec, int size) : vec_{vec}, pointer_{size} {}

    bool operator!=(const It<T>& other) const
    {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    bool operator==(const It<T>& other) const
    {
        return pointer_ == other.pointer_;
    }

    It& operator++()
    {
        ++pointer_;            
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() const
    {
        return vec_.at(pointer_);   
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Vector
{
    std::vector<T> vec_;

    void push_back(T item)
    {
        vec_.push_back(item);
    };

    It<T> begin()
    {
        return It<T>(vec_);
    }

    It<T> end()
    {
        return It<T>(vec_, vec_.size());
    }
};

int main()
{
  Vector<int> vec;
  vec.push_back(1);
  vec.push_back(2);
  vec.push_back(3);

  bool first = true;
  for (It<int> it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
  {
      if (first) //modify container once while iterating
      {
          vec.push_back(4);
          first = false;
      }

      std::cout << *it << '\n'; //print it 
      (*it)++;                  //change it
  }

  for (It<int> it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
  {
      std::cout << *it << '\n'; //should see changed value
  }
}
```