# Calling iterator constructor from another class

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am trying to write `graph` class as a template class. As answered in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container), I was trying to implement `graph` in term of `std::set` , here is what I have wrote till now.

```
    #include <set>

    template <class T, 
            class Container = std::set<T> >
    class graph {
    public:
        class iterator { 
        public:
            iterator() {
                std::set<T>::iterator();
            }
            iterator(const iterator&) {
                std::set<T>::iterator();
            }
            ~iterator() {
                std::set<T>::~iterator();
            }
```

What I am looking for here is whenever `graph::itertor` is called, internally it should called `set::iterator`, Is this approach ok, and why `~iterator()` is not getting compiled.

Comment: You're not calling constructors here, you're constructing temporary objects, which does, well, exactly nothing.

Comment: Your example is not complete. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to provide iterators for your graph class, and graph's iterators are nothing but the iterators of the underlying container type. If so, then you should actually be doing this,

```
template <class T,  class Container = std::set<T> >
class graph 
{
public:
    typedef typename Container::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename Container::const_iterator const_iterator;

    //...
};
```

As for your code, I would say that `std::set<T>::iterator()` creates a temporary object, and the temporary gets destroyed at the end of the full expression. It's story ends there. And `std::set<T>::~iterator()` wouldn't even compile.