# C++ problems with own iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, iteration

*Edit1: Code translated to english.*

*Edit2: `iterator` and `const_iterator` definitions moved from `DoubleList.cpp` to `DoubleList.h` (thanks to Casey).*

I'm creating my own container (**Abstract double list**) with iterator. I was looked for many informations about iterators on google, [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/), [some Helsinky](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/alglib/k06/lectures/iterators.html#difference-type) and still I'm searching on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container/7759622#7759622), but I'm still really confused. I will give you parts of my codes and I will try to explain it in coments, what I don't understand. Mainly I don't understand why I have errors in `StudentRecord.cpp` on line 13:

- 8    IntelliSense: no operator "++" matches these operands
- 7    IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed
- Error    6   error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a
  left-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable
  conversion)
- Error    4   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
  'SemestralWork::DoubleList::iterator' to 'int'
- Error    2   error C2079: 'it' uses undefined class
  'SemestralWork::DoubleList::iterator'
- Error    3   error C2027: use of undefined type
  'SemestralWork::DoubleList::iterator'
- Error    5   error C2027: use of undefined type
  'SemestralWork::DoubleList::iterator'

I will be glad for every advice and sorry for my bad english.

**StudentRecord.cpp (just part)**

```
1. #include "StdAfx.h"
2. #include "StudentRecord.h"
3. using namespace SemestralWork;
4. 
5. StudentRecord::StudentRecord(void)
6. {
7. }
8. 
9. Student &StudentRecord::SearchStudent(const string &ID){
10.     Student * SearchedStudent;
11.     Student * EmptyStudent = NULL;
12.     
13.     for(DoubleList<Student>::iterator it = List->begin(); it != List->end(); ++it){
14.         if(ID == List->AccessActual().getID()){
15.             SearchedStudent = &List->AccessActual();
16.             return *SearchedStudent;
17.         }
18.     }
19.     return *EmptyStudent;
20. }
```

**StudentRecord.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Student.h"
#include "DoubleList.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace SemestralWork;

class StudentRecord{

private:
    DoubleList<Student> *List;
public:
    StudentRecord(void);
    ~StudentRecord(void);
    Student &SearchStudent(const string &ID);
    void addStudent(const Student &student, Student::Position position = Student::Position::LAST);
    Student RemoveStudent(const string &ID);
    void WriteAllStudents(void);
    void Cancel(void);
};
```

**DoubleList.cpp (just iterators, begins, ends)**

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "DoubleList.h"
using namespace SemestralWork;

...

template<typename T>
typename DoubleList<T>::iterator DoubleList<T>::begin(){
    return AccesFirst();         // = access first value
}

template<typename T>
typename DoubleList<T>::iterator DoubleList<T>::end(){
    return AccessLast();      // = access last value
}

template<typename T>
typename DoubleList<T>::const_iterator DoubleList<T>::cbegin(){
    return AccesFirst();         //or return const_iterator(this); ??
}

template<typename T>
typename DoubleList<T>::const_iterator DoubleList<T>::cend(){
    return AccessLast();      //or return const_iterator(); ??
}
```

**DoubleList.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace SemestralWork{

    template <typename T>
    class DoubleList {
    protected:
        template <class U>
        class Node{
            Node<U> *next;
            Node<U> *previous;
            U *data;
        public:
            Node(U *data){
                next= NULL;
                previous= NULL;
                this->data = data;
            }
            void SetNext(Node<U> *next) { 
                this->next = next; 
            }
            Node<U> *GetNext(){ return next; }
            void SetPrevious(Node<U> *previous) { 
                this->previous= previous; 
            }
            Node<U> *GetPrevious(){ return previous; }
            U *GetData() { return data; }
        };
    private:
        Node<T> * actual;
        Node<T> * first;
        Node<T> * last;
        int numberOfElements;

    public:
        typedef void (*PointerFunction)(const T);
        DoubleList(void);
        ~DoubleList(void);
        bool IsEmpty(void) const;
        int NumberOfElements() const;

        void AddFirst(const T &);
        void AddLast(const T &);
        void AddNext(const T &);
        void AddPrevious(const T &);

        T &AccessActual(void);
        T &AccesFirst(void);
        T &AccessLast(void);
        T &AccesNext(void);
        T &AccesPrevious(void);

        T RemoveFirst(void);
        T RemoveLast(void);
        T RemoveActual(void);
        T RemoveNext(void);
        T RemovePrevious(void);

        void Search(PointerFunction) const;
        void Cancel(void);

        class iterator {

        public:
            typedef T value_type;
            typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;      //maybe int
            typedef T* pointer;
            typedef T& reference;
            typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
            typedef iterator self_type;
            Node<T> * ptr;

            iterator();                      //just like that?
            iterator(const iterator& mit){}  //just like that?
            ~iterator();

            iterator& operator++(){
                ptr = ptr->GetNext();
                return *this;
            }
            iterator operator++(int){
                iterator tmp = *this;   //iterator tmp(*this)
                operator++();
                return tmp;
            }
            bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) {return ptr==rhs.ptr;}     
            bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) {return ptr!=rhs.ptr;}
            Node<T>& operator*() {return ptr->GetData();}
            Node<T>* operator->(){return ptr->GetData();}

        };
        class const_iterator{
            //not programmed yet...
        };
        iterator begin();
        iterator end();
        const_iterator cbegin();
        const_iterator cend();
    };
}
```

**Student.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    string firstName, lastName, ID;
public:
    Student(string, string, string);
    ~Student(void);
    string getFirstName();
    string getLastName();
    string getID();
    enum Position{ FIRST, LAST, ACTUAL, PREVIOUS, NEXT};
};
```

Comment: Writing your own linked-list and iterators for it is for learning purposes, right?

Comment: Consider to translate the code to english, could help readers a lot.

Comment: Why is your `template` implementation in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: Yes, it's for my semestral work... Ok, I edit it... It's my first question here, sorry

Comment: Yakk: I see, that works too without next templates, thanks for it, but  other problems still persist.

Comment: ad Yakk: but DoubleList must be allegedly universal class... Our teacher want it. :D

Comment: You have errors because the definition of `DoubleList<T>::iterator` is hidden away in a .cpp file, when it needs to be visible to the rest of the program that uses it (e.g., line 13 in Student.cpp). Move the iterator definition into DoubleList.h.

Comment: Casey: Nice, it works! But now I have 4 LNK2019 errors in the same lines StudentRecord.obj, can it to be bad operator->() overload?