# "no type named 'const_reference' " error when implementing a string-like class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a class with similar behavior to std::string and I'm getting the error in the std::copy line:

```
Str& operator+=(const Str& s){
    std::copy(s.data.begin(), s.data.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
    return *this;
}
```

'data' is an object of type vec < char> , and vec is a vector-like class that I implemented myself and it seems to be working fine on its own.

It also says this:

C:\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2........\include\c++\3.4.2\bits\stl_iterator.h||In instantiation of `std::back_insert_iterator < vec< char> >':|

Comment: Well does your `vec<char>` have a `const_reference` type?

Comment: I added a 'typedef const T& const_reference' and it compiled, now let's see if it works. Thanks everyone for the answers, wish I could upvote you all.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if they helped by clicking the tick.

Comment: Chapter 12 of "Accelerated C++", by A. Koenig & B. E. Moo. Would you please cite them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your `vec` doesn't meet the Container Requirements, so it's not guaranteed to be usable by standard facilities (such as `back_inserter`) that work with containers.

The requirements are specified in Table 96 in C++11, although Table 65 in C++98 is probably more appropriate for your ancient compiler. One of those requirements is a nested `const_reference` type.

Answer (score 3):

Check the requirements for `std::back_inserter` and `std::copy`. In particular, `std::back_inserter` expects an argument which fulfils the concept *Container*. At the very least this means implementing §23.2.1 of the standard, and one of the requirements listed there is:

> `X::const_reference` |  const lvalue of `T`  |  compile time

I.e. a `typedef const_reference` inside the container type.

Answer (score 2):

`back_inserter` is a convinience function which constructs a `back_insert_iterator` on the container; in this case, `data`.

`data`, you've said, is your own homegrown `vector`-type class.  In order for this to work, your `vector` class must have a `const_reference` typedef defined.  Something like this:

```
template <typename Item>
class Vec
{
public:
  typedef const Item& const_reference;
};
```

There are a number of other requirements for any implementation of a container.  These are outlined in the C++03 Standard, in section **23.1 Container Requirements** including Table 65.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container) for a discussion of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

> typedef T value_type;
>   typedef const value_type& const_reference;

in your vec<T> body.

Answer (score 0):

Question needs some more details like your vec class.

What exactly is the error that you are getting? Please share more info on the error. console log would be helpful.

std::copy takes in two input iterators.(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)
Are you sure that your vector like class is handling the iterators correctly?

Also please check if your vec support the container requirements needed by back_inserter. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/

Comment: -1:  A couple problems here.  First, there are enough details presented to at least take a pretty close guess as to the problem.  See the other answers.  Second, this "answer" is really just a bunch of questions for the OP, asking for clarification.  As such, this should be posted as a *comment*, not an *answer*.

Comment: I didn't have enough credits for posting the comment.