# Pointer to a vector doesn't point

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have simplified the code as much as possible. 
So I have two class:

```
class EntityManager
{
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Entity> > getEntities()
        {
            return std::make_shared<std::vector<Entity> >(m_entities);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Entity> m_entities{};
};
```

and

```
class System
{
    public:
        void loadEntities(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Entity> > entities)
        {
            m_entities = entities;
        }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Entity> > m_entities;
};
```

Now basically I want the m_entities of System to point to the m_entities of EntityManager.

I did this:

```
system = System();
system.loadEntities(m_entityManager.getEntities());
```

But then I pushed back an element into the m_entities vector of EntityManager and this element wasn't added in the m_entities vector of System, which means my pointer doesn't point.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple code is good but it still must be complete. Read again about how to construct a [MCVE].

Comment: Don't think you need a shared pointer there. `EntityManager` is the obvious owner of the entity list and it sure looks like `System` owns the  `EntityManager`. All of the ownership and lifetimes should be known.

Comment: What do you mean by should be known? And what do you suggest to use?

Comment: `System` contains an `EntityManager`.  `EntityManager` contains a `vector` of `Entity`. This `vector` cannot be destroyed before the `EntityManager` and the `EntityManager` cannot be destroyed before `System`. Ergo the lifespan of all objects is known and nothing is destroyed before `System`is destroyed, so you have no need to fear `System` using raw pointers to the `vector`. The pointer cannot be invalidated before the user is finished with it. That said, add a `getEntity` function to `EntityManager` and there is no need for `System` to even know there is a `vector`.

Comment: You could make `EntityManager::m_entities` to be a shared pointer initialized via constructor and fixup the rest of the code thereafter, [something like this](http://ideone.com/zcQTmJ), but I'm not certain it will ultimately solve the *real* problem you're set upon. This has a feeling of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), so think hard about what you're really doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line: `return std::make_shared<std::vector<Entity> >(m_entities);`

What is happening is that the `shared_ptr` manages a new `std::vectory<Entity>` container which is initialized as a copy of `m_entities`. Therefore, modifying the instance in the `shared_ptr` doesn't modify the data member in the `EntityManager` class and of course the `shared_ptr` won't see changes made to `EntityManager::m_entities`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to solve it using a shared_ptr?

Comment: @Urefeu Yes, but there is no point. You don't need a shared pointer.

Comment: @Urefeu Why the obsession with shared_ptr here?

Comment: @Urefeu: You appear to be taking huge sweeping statements and applying them to your code without applying any actual thought or reasoning to your choices. Use `shared_ptr` when it's appropriate, not because somebody told you not to use raw pointers. Why do you need any pointers at all?

Comment: And I need it because that is what I have explained, I want my System's m_entities to be like the EntityManager's one at any time.

Comment: @Urefeu See the [answer provided by Lightness Races in Orbit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38231385/4505712) which states you could make `m_entities` in `EntityManager` a `shared_ptr`. **However, heed the information everyone is giving you.** You don't have to use `shared_ptr` for this, you may not need pointers at all, there are cicumstances where raw pointers are perfectly fine, etc.

Comment: @Urefeu It's unclear what you're doing versus what is required/necessary. Why can't you use normal stack allocated objects and copy semantics?

Comment: I am not familiar with that, I have always done it with pointers (not shared ones though).

Comment: @Urefeu A good guideline is to not use dynamic allocation (i.e., `new`) unless you need to. (i.e., prefer stack allocation `int x = 0;` over dynamic allocation `int* x = new int(0);`).

Comment: That's what I try to do, but in order to have the same instance at two different places, what can I do but a reference/pointer?

Comment: Why do you **_need_** the same instance in more than one place as opposed to copying? Why shouldn't the `EntityManager` be copied or shared instead of it's internal data? Also, see [the comment by user4581301](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231160/pointer-to-a-vector-doesnt-point/38231224?noredirect=1#comment63884919_38231160). I think all the questions surround _why you think you **need** to do it the way you're trying to do it_ (i.e., maybe you're correct but explain the requirements and constraints in your question).

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_shared` doesn't "make this thing shared"; it "makes a thing that will be shared".

So, you can't just make a shared pointer out of nowhere that points to something that already exists.

Your code dynamically allocates a `std::vector`, *copy constructed* from `m_entities` and managed by a `std::shared_ptr`. It's shorthand for this:

```
std::vector<Entity>* ptr_to_copy = new std::vector<Entity>(m_entities);
return std::shared_ptr(ptr_to_copy);
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do, from the code that (by your own admission) does not achieve that goal. But it seems unlikely that `std::shared_ptr` is appropriate here.

If it is, then make the vector dynamically-allocated and shared from the start; otherwise, just return a reference to the vector as it is.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with the use of different pointers then. When should I use raw, shared, unique ones... ?

Comment: @Urefeu Research other questions on this same topic and then possibly ask a _new question_.

Comment: @Urefeu Covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706192/which-kind-of-pointer-do-i-use-when The names have changed slightly since that post, but the logic still holds.

Answer (score 0):

Hack example of a pointer-free solution.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//Hack-sample Entity class
class Entity
{
    public:
        Entity(const char * name): m_name(name)
        {

        }
        void print() // this is stupid in real life. Prefer a << overload
        {
            std::cout << "Hi! I'm " << m_name << "!\n"; 
        }
    private:
        std::string m_name;
};

class EntityManager
{
    private:
        std::vector<Entity> m_entities;

    public:
        // hide the fact that a vector is being used to store the entities.
        // you can now swap out the vector for most standard containers without
        // changing any code other than the using and the declaration of m_entities
        using iterator = std::vector<Entity>::iterator;

        EntityManager(): m_entities({"bob", "bill"}) 
                         // just pre-loading a few test entities
        {
            // RAII says you should load the entities from their source here
        }
        // get the first entity. 
        iterator begin()
        {
            return m_entities.begin();
        }
        // get the end of the entity list
        iterator end()
        {
            return m_entities.end();
        }

        // adds an entity
        void addEntity(const Entity & entity)
        {
            m_entities.push_back(entity);
        }

        // removes an entity
        iterator removeEntity(iterator rem)
        {
            return m_entities.erase(rem);
        }

};

class System
{
    public:

        // example method to show System working with EntityManager by printing all of the Entities
        void printEntities()
        {
            for (EntityManager::iterator it = m_entityManager.begin();
                 it != m_entityManager.end();
                 ++it)
            {
                it->print();
            }
        }

        // example method to show System working with EntityManager by adding Entities
        void addMoreEntities()
        {
            m_entityManager.addEntity(Entity("Ted \"Theodore\" Logan"));
            m_entityManager.addEntity(Entity("Excellent!!!"));
        }

    private:
        EntityManager m_entityManager ;
};

// sample test
int main()
{
    System test;

    test.printEntities();
    test.addMoreEntities();
    test.printEntities();

}
```

THIS HAS BEEN A HACK. THIS HAS ONLY BEEN A HACK.

If you want to do `EntityManager` right, see [Writing your own STL Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container/7759622#7759622) for hints. If you want all of the bells and whistles, the job is fairly complicated. Depending on how you are using `EntityManager` and the complexity of the `Entity` management logic, you may be better off discarding `EntityManager` and just using the plain, old `std::vector`.

Addendum: [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)