# Quicker way to insert into list?

Tags: c++, list, insert

I'm having a hard time writing an efficient way to insert a large volume of values into a list, without using maps.  The code I have currently looks as follows:

```
list<pair<int, vector<int>>> myList;

void key_value_sequences::insert(int key, int value){
    for(it=myList.begin(); it!=myList.end(); ++it){
        if(it->first==key){
            it->second.push_back(value);
            return;
        }
    }
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(value);
    myList.push_back(make_pair(key, v));
    myList.sort();
    return;
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: whats the type of myList?

Comment: @Bitonator edited op

Comment: Looks like you really want a map of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You're close; since you appear to have an in-order list, try this:

```
void key_value_sequences::insert(int key, int value){
    for(it=myList.begin(); it!=myList.end(); ++it){
        if(it->first==key){
            it->second.push_back(value);
            return;
        }
        else if (it->first > key) // Or <, depending on order
        {
            vector<int> v;
            v.push_back(value);
            myList.insert(it, make_pair(key, v));
            return;
        }
    }
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(value);
    myList.push_back(make_pair(key, v));
}
```

Basically, once you go one past the `key`, insert the new entry, or if you get to the end, you've got the largest `key`, so push it to the back. Thus you can keep the list sorted.

Comment: looks like this still runs in linear time, but am shooting more for constant

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, for **O(1)** rather than **O(N)** you would need either an `std::map` (**O(logN)**?) or a hash table, **O(1)** without collisions. Your original version does **N + N log N** comparisons, I think, for a new element and this does an average of **N / 2**.

Comment: Is there a somewhat simple way to change this to a hash table without throwing it all away?

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is sorted, so it might be a simple drop-in replacement.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use map, as the only headers I am working with are list, vector, and algorithm

Comment: @Gman A simple hash table can be made from a `vector<list<TYPE>>` Since `TYPE` is `int`, the hashing algorithm could be something simple like `value%myList.size()`. The list handles collisions.

Comment: @Gman My example is crack. I outlined a set, not a hash table in that comment. I'll post a better one in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hash table using a `vector` and a `list`.

The vector contains a list of collided keys. A smart hash table will adjust it's size and rehash to minimize collisions. This is not a smart hash table.

The `vector` is used as the outer container because it has much faster iteration. There is a string case for the inner container also being a `vector` because `list`s... they kinda suck unless you add and remove more than you iterate. [I'll let the big man himself explain.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

class poor_mans_hash
{
    std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int,int>>> hash_table;

    int hash(int val)
    {
        return abs(val%static_cast<int>(hash_table.size()));
        // abs because a negative number makes a very explosive vector index
    }
public:
    poor_mans_hash(int size): hash_table(size)
    {
        // all work done in member initialization list
    }

    void insert(int key,
                int val)
    {
        // get list for correct element
        std::list<std::pair<int,int>> &collisionlist = hash_table[hash(key)];

        // see if key is in list
        for (std::pair<int,int> &test: collisionlist)
        {
            if (key == test.first)
            {
                test.second = val; // update existing
                return;
            }
        }
        // key not found. Add it.
        collisionlist.push_back(std::pair<int,int>(key, val));
    }

    bool find(int key)
    {
        for (std::pair<int,int> &test: hash_table[hash(key)])
        {
            if (key == test.first)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    int & get(int key)
    {
        for (std::pair<int,int> &test: hash_table[hash(key)])
        {
            if (key == test.first)
            {
                // found key. Return value
                return test.second;
            }
        }

        // Not found. 
        throw std::out_of_range("No such key");
    }
};

int main()
{
    poor_mans_hash test(50);

    test.insert(1, 1);
    std::cout << "1: " << test.get(1) << std::endl;
    try
    {
        std::cout << test.get(51) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range &e)
    {
        std::cout << "could not get 51: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    test.insert(11, 11);
    test.insert(21, 21);
    test.insert(51, 51);
    std::cout << "1: " << test.get(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "51: " << test.get(51) << std::endl;
    test.insert(1, 2);
    std::cout << "1: " << test.get(1) << std::endl;

}
```

Possible improvements to this are many. Rehashing and smarter organizing, for one thing. For another, here's a write up on all the fun things you can do to make this a good, library-like container [Writing your own STL Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container/7759622#7759622)