# How to write a class in c++ with proper iterators so it can be used by standard library containers and algorithms

Tags: c++, std

Suppose I wrote a class in c++ like this:

```
class data
{
private:
    int a,b,c,d;
public:
    data(){
        a=b=c=d=0;
    }
    data(int aa,int bb, int cc, int dd)
    {
        a=aa,b=bb,c=cc,d=dd;
    }
    int get_b(){return b;}
    int get_a(){return a;}
};
```

Now I know want to learn how to write operators and iterators for this class so that it can be used with standard library containers

Like: `set<string> x;` this is possible. I want to use this **data** class as `set<data> x;` and want to use iterators like `set<data>::iterator it;`

I have tried to google out the procedure, but nowhere could find an example implementation which would actually explain the procedure.

Comment: Do you mean `data` be like a container?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing your own STL Container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container)

Comment: Refer to Section 23.2.1 of the C++11 standard for requirements of the standard containers.  Similarly, look in Section 24.2 for requirements of iterators.

Comment: The OOP tag is wrong, because generic programming is not OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like: set x; this is possible. I want to use this data class
>   as set x; and want to use iterators like set::iterator it;

I believe you want to use  you class as data to fit into standard containers (vector/set etc).

**For Sequence Containers (Vector)**

```
int main()
{
    data d1(1, 2);
    data d2(3, 4);

    vector<data> vec{d1, d2};  //initialize your container with your "data" type objects.
    for(auto iter = vec.begin(), iter != vec.end();iter++)
        cout<<*iter;     //for this you need to implement "operator<<" in your data class.    
    return 0;
}
```

**For Associative Containers (Set)**

```
int main()
{
    data d1(1, 2);
    data d2(3, 4);
    //you need to impelment "< or >" relational operator in you data class.
    set<data> st{d1, d2};  //initialize your container with your "data" type objects.
    for(auto iter = vec.begin(), iter != vec.end();iter++)
        cout<<*iter;     //for this you need to implement "operator<<" in your data class.    
    return 0;
}
```

Add this in your class definition.

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const base& obj)
{
    return (os<<obj.memVariable);
}
```

Comment: by operator << you mean left shift ?

Comment: @AkaSaito no, i meant output stream operator..added it in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :) Really grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it in a `std::set`, `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_set` you need to implement a ***"weak less than operator"***

```
bool operator<(const data& other_data) {
   return ....;
}
```

For other containers like `std::vector`, `std::deque`, std::list data is ok as it is.