# How to create iterator for member element from the iterator of std container?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I need to create an iterator only for member element to iterate through container.

For example:

```
class A { int x; char y; };

std::vector<A> mycoll = {{10,'a'}, {20,'b'}, {30,'c'} };
```

Here `mycoll.begin()` will give me iterator of type A

But I require to write iterator to iterate over specific member ( say x `A.x` ) and let `int_ite` be the iterator for that integer.

Then I require

`*(int_ite.begin() )` to return 10

`*(++int_ite.begin() )` to return 20

and so on

also `.end()` would give end of iteration.

Is there any elegant way to create such an iterator?
I require it to pass it to `std::lower_bound()`

Comment: You can't use `int_ite.begin()->x`?

Comment: What exactly did you find to be a problem in creating the iterator? Have you tried to write the iterator yet?

Comment: sure it is possible to implement something like an iterator only returning the field _x_, but so strange and complicated for nothing

Comment: @NathanOliver ```int_ite.begin()->x``` will give me the element directly. But I need to create iterator for that element to pass it to a function.

Comment: @SergeyA its not

Comment: @addy, just write a class, implement the usual iterator operations `*`, `++` etc. Formally you can look up the iterator requirements, implement all of those and you have an iterator. It's tedious but not difficult.

Comment: why do you need this? for example if you want to sort `mycoll` you would write a comparator that compares the member instead of having to create iterators that when dereferenced yield the member

Comment: @user463035818  For cases like std::sort it can be done without writing iterator
I require it to pass it to std::lower_bound()

Comment: better add that to the question, as it helps to answer

Comment: for `std::lower_bound` you don't need it either, a custom comparer do the job.

Comment: Sidenote: Irf you ever find yourself in a position where you really do need to do this, [Mooing Duck has an excellent piece](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759622/4581301) on how to get started making a container and its iterators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may create view:

```
std::vector<A> mycoll = {{10,'a'}, {20,'b'}, {30,'c'} };

for (auto e : mycoll | ranges::view::transform(&A::x)) {
    std::cout << e << " "; // 10 20 30
}
```

And for `lower_bound`, range-v3 has projection:

```
auto it = ranges::v3::lower_bound(mycoll, value, std::less<>{}, &A::x);
// return iterator of mycoll directly :-)
```

Else with std, you my use custom comparer with `std::lower_bound`

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(mycoll.begin(), mycoll.end(),
                           value,
                           [](const A& a, int x){ return a.x < x; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Solution to the problem was not so obvious.

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) (overload (2)):

> ```
> template< class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare >
> ForwardIt lower_bound( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp );
> ```

To find the lower bound with respect to the member `x`, you can pass a comparator that compares that member as the last parameter.

You typically pass a functor to algorithms that specifies how the container elements are processed or evaluated, instead of having to write complicated iterators. The support for writing your own fancy iterators is rather poor in the standard library, while the algorithms are rather powerful.