# Writing an STL-compatible container - implicit requirements

Tags: c++, containers

I'm trying to learn a bit about data structures and writing containers which could be used by as much of "the C++" as possible. I know that to support ranged for a class needs to have `begin()` and `end()` or that `std::back_inserter` uses `push_back()` to do its job but that's about all.

Is there a list of this type of requirements a container must meet to be fully compatible with all the iterators, container adaptors and algorithms?

Comment: Handy reading: [Writing your own STL Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container).

Comment: @cigien The standard specifies what standard containers should be, not necessarily what is the bare minimum a custom container should have to make use of the rest of the STL

Comment: Different containers have different requirements for what kind of operations their elements must support.  There is no standard "all containers must do this" kind of requirement