# C++ Iterator for C Linked Lists: to use range-based for loops

Tags: c++, iterator

I am working with legacy `C` code and the new code is written in `C++`. To use the C++ standard library, I wrote a simple `Iterator` for the legacy `LinkedList` as shown below after reading through Bjarne Stroustrup's blog post on [Adaptation](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/12/myths-1).

My question is:

1. I want to create another `Iterator` for another `struct` say `struct TokenList`. I am not sure how to use `namespace` and still be able to use the *range-based* `for` loops. Any pointers would be helpful.
2. Are the adapters for the `Iterator` namely: `begin`, `end`, `++`, `*`, `!=` correct? Currently, I'm an interested in reading the contents of the `LinkedList` using range-based `for` loops.

[Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9b964d095c15cd4)

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

struct LinkedList {
    double v;
    LinkedList *next;
};

struct Iterator {
    LinkedList *current;
    LinkedList &c;
};

Iterator begin(LinkedList *c) { return Iterator {c, *c}; }
Iterator end(LinkedList *c) { return Iterator {nullptr, *c}; }
Iterator &operator++(Iterator &p) { p.current = p.current->next; return p; }
LinkedList *operator*(Iterator p) { return p.current; }
bool operator!=(Iterator lhs, Iterator rhs) { return (lhs.current != rhs.current); }

int main()
{
    LinkedList *node1 = new LinkedList;
    LinkedList *node2 = new LinkedList;
    LinkedList *node3 = new LinkedList;

    node1->v = 1; node1->next = node2;
    node2->v = 2; node2->next = node3;
    node3->v = 3; node3->next = nullptr;

    printf("// C style: iteration\n");
    for (auto ptr = node1; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%e\n", ptr->v);
    }

    auto head = node1;
    // make use of begin(), end(), ++, != and *
    printf("// Modern C++ style: range based for-loop\n");
    for (const auto& it : head) {
        printf("%e\n", it->v);
    }

    delete node3;
    delete node2;
    delete node1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Implementing one's owned linked list is a useful programming excersize that's given in pretty much every introductory course on programming. But when one is faced with a real task, simply using `std::list` is much simpler. Can you clarify what specific problem you are trying to solve, using your own linked list implementation, that cannot be solved simply by using `std::list`, and everything that goes with it?

Comment: The old code seems to need some rework anyway. `LinkedList` is a _node_ in a linked list. Utterly confusing.

Comment: What does namespace have to do with this?  Your iterator class should belong to your container, not the global scope level.  The storage of a reference value in the iterator makes no sense.  It's super sketchy.  Don't do that.

Comment: Note also your deletion is incorrect.  You cannot advance the iterator on a deleted node.

Comment: The best way to get a range-based for loop going would be to wrap the C-Style linked list in a a class that performed the same basic tasks as a library container with the same interface as used in the library containers. [Helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators are pseudo-pointer types.  That means they themselves are regular.

```
struct Iterator {
  LinkedList *current;
  LinkedList &c;
};
```

Here you mix references and pointers.  This is a serious anti-pattern, as what does assignment do?  There is no sensible answer.

I would remove the `c` member entirely.

Next you need to broadcast an iterator type.  Yours looks like a forward iterator.  All end iterators can be equal.

```
Iterator begin(LinkedList *c) { return Iterator {c, *c}; }
Iterator end(LinkedList *c) { return Iterator {nullptr, *c}; }
```

These look ok.  Just remove `*c`.

Note that the name does not have to be `Iterator`.  `begin`/`end` must be defined in the namespace of `LinkedList`, but the return type does not have to be.

```
Iterator &operator++(Iterator &p) { p.current = p.current->next; return p; }
```

I usually implement this as a member function, and implement both pre and post increment; post is implemented using pre and copy.

```
LinkedList *operator*(Iterator p) { return p.current; }
```

This is wrong.  It should return `*p.current` as a `double&`.

```
bool operator!=(Iterator lhs, Iterator rhs) { return (lhs.current != rhs.current); }
```

sure.  Also implement `==` as `!(lhs!=rhs)`.

Look up the forward iterator concept and forward iterator tag.  Include the types needed for `std::iterator_traits`.

For other things to iterate, give the iterator a different name.  This can be via a different namespace.

If the thing that differs is just the type of the value, you can make it a template pretty easy.  Then you only have to manually write `begin`/`end`.

If the name of `v` also changes, you could use ADL on a `GetValue(List*)` function you write as a customization point.

---

Now, being usable in a ranged based for is different than being an iterator.  Ranged based for is a tad easier; but the above upgrades you to a full forward iterator, which in turn reduces surprise when you try to use a std algorithm or basically anything else.

---

[How I would write it](https://godbolt.org/z/aj7qfKTPj):

```
// Iteration::LinkedListIterator<X> assumes that X is a linked list node
// with members ->next and ->value.  If it isn't, override the customization
// points GetNextNode and GetListElement in the namespace of X.

namespace Iteration {
  template<class List>
  List* GetNextNode( List* l ) {
    if (!l) return l;
    return l->next;
  }
  template<class List>
  decltype(auto) GetListElement( List* l ) {
    return l->value;
  }
  template<class List>
  struct LinkedListIterator {

    using self=LinkedListIterator;
    List *current;
    self& operator++(){ current = GetNextNode(current); return *this; }
    self operator++(int)&{ auto copy = *this; ++*this; return copy; }
    decltype(auto) operator*() {
      return GetListElement(current);
    }
    decltype(auto) operator*() const {
      return GetListElement(current);
    }
    auto operator->() {
      return std::addressof(GetListElement(current));
    }
    auto operator->() const {
      return std::addressof(GetListElement(current));
    }
    friend bool operator==(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
      return lhs.current == rhs.current;
    }
    friend bool operator!=(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
      return lhs.current != rhs.current;
    }

    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(GetListElement(std::declval<List*>()))>;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;
  };
};

struct LinkedList {
    double v;
    LinkedList *next;
};

// customization point; the name of 
double& GetListElement( LinkedList* l ) { return l->v; }
double const& GetListElement( LinkedList const* l ) { return l->v; }
Iteration::LinkedListIterator<LinkedList> begin( LinkedList* l ) {
  return {l};
}
Iteration::LinkedListIterator<LinkedList> end( LinkedList* l ) {
  return {nullptr};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small modification of [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70297824) using C++20 concepts to find member functions for GetNextNode/GetListElement plus support for bidirectional iteration.

```cpp
namespace Iteration {
    template<class List>
    List* GetNextNode(List* l) {
        if (!l) return l;
        return l->next;
    }
    template<class List>
    List* GetPreviousNode(List* l) {
        if (!l) return l;
        return l->prev;
    }
    template<class List>
    decltype(auto) GetListElement(List* l) {
        return l;
    }
    template<class T>
    concept HasGetNextNodeMember = requires(T a) {
        a.GetNextNode();
    };
    template<class T>
    concept HasGetPreviousNodeMember = requires(T a) {
        a.GetPreviousNode();
    };
    template<class T>
    concept HasGetListElement = requires(T a) {
        a.GetListElement();
    };
    template<class T>
    concept HasPrevious = requires(T a) {
        HasGetPreviousNodeMember<T> || a.prev;
    };

    template<class List>
    struct LinkedListIterator {
    private:
        static List* next(List* el)
        {
            if (!el) return el;
            if constexpr (HasGetNextNodeMember<List>)
                return el->GetNextNode();
            else
                return GetNextNode(el);
        }
        static List* prev(List* el)
        {
            if (!el) return el;
            if constexpr (HasGetPreviousNodeMember<List>)
                return el->GetPreviousNode();
            else
                return GetPreviousNode(el);
        }
        static auto element(List* el)
        {
            if constexpr (HasGetListElement<List>)
                return el->GetListElement();
            else
                return GetListElement(el);
        }
    public:
        using self = LinkedListIterator;
        List* current;

        self& operator++() { current = next(current); return *this; }
        self operator++(int)& { auto copy = *this; ++*this; return copy; }

        std::enable_if_t<HasPrevious<List>, self&> operator--() { current = prev(current); return *this; }
        std::enable_if_t<HasPrevious<List>, self&> operator--(int)& { auto copy = *this; ++*this; return copy; }

        decltype(auto) operator*() {
            return element(current);
        }
        decltype(auto) operator*() const {
            return element(current);
        }
        auto operator->() {
            return std::addressof(element(current));
        }
        auto operator->() const {
            return std::addressof(element(current));
        }
        friend bool operator==(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
            return lhs.current == rhs.current;
        }
        friend bool operator!=(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
            return lhs.current != rhs.current;
        }

        using iterator_category = std::conditional_t<HasPrevious<List>, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, std::forward_iterator_tag>;
        using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(element(std::declval<List*>()))>;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using reference = value_type&;
    };
};
```

You can use it like

```
struct LinkedList {
    double v;
    LinkedList *next;
};

double& GetListElement( LinkedList* l ) { return l->v; }
double const& GetListElement( LinkedList const* l ) { return l->v; }
```

or for bidirectional iterator

```
struct DoublyLinkedList {
    double v;
    DoublyLinkedList *next;
    DoublyLinkedList *prev;
};

double& GetListElement( DoublyLinkedList* l ) { return l->v; }
double const& GetListElement( DoublyLinkedList const* l ) { return l->v; }
```

or use a wrapper over the C class

```
struct DoublyLinkedList {
    double v;
    DoublyLinkedList *next;
    DoublyLinkedList *prev;
};

struct DoublyLinkedListWrapper : DoublyLinkedList {
    DoublyLinkedListWrapper* GetNextNode() const { return reinterpret_cast<DoublyLinkedListWrapper*>(next); }
    DoublyLinkedListWrapper* GetPrevNode() const { return reinterpret_cast<DoublyLinkedListWrapper*>(prev); }

    double& GetListElement() { return v; }
}
```