# Difference in complexity guarantee of vector and list from the table

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

While trying to understand the difference in complexity guarantee between a vector and a list I am referring to this [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181693/what-are-the-complexity-guarantees-of-the-standard-containers) now I am not sure how to read the table in order to extract the difference in complexity guarantee between a vector and a list. From what I understand from the table is that a vector and list are both sequence containers however a vector fits into a category of a (forward,reverse and random) container however a list fits into the category of only a Forward and reverse container. Any suggestions on how I could use this information to interpret the table and extract a point which separates a vector from a list based on the complexity guarantee?

Comment: That table seems rather incomplete. You might be better off reading a C++ library tutorial/reference to learn (for example) that random element access is O(1) for vectors but O(n) for lists; that inserting it an arbitrary point is O(1) for lists but O(n) for vectors; and much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any algorithm that requires a random access iterator can be used with `std::vector` but cannot be used with `std::list`. `std::sort` is one example; that's why `std::list` has its own `sort` function.