# Does the std::vector implementation use an internal array or linked list or other?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, time-complexity

I've been told that std::vector has a C-style array on the inside implementation, but would that not negate the entire purpose of having a dynamic container?

So is inserting a value in a vector an O(n) operation? Or is it O(1) like in a linked-list?

Comment: The linked list class in C++ is `std::list`.  Thus a `std::vector` is not a linked list -- it *is* basically a dynamic array and has insertion times no different than what you would expect (`O(n)`), unless inserted at the end of the sequence.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181693/what-are-the-complexity-guarantees-of-the-standard-containers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C++11 standard, in the "sequence containers" library section (emphasis mine):

> [23.3.6.1 Class template `vector` overview][vector.overview]
>   A vector is a sequence container that supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the
>   end; *insert and erase in the middle take linear time*. Storage management is handled automatically, though
>   hints can be given to improve efficiency.

This does not defeat the purpose of dynamic size -- part of the point of vector is that not only is it very fast to access a single element, but scanning over the vector has very good *memory locality* because everything is tightly packed together. In practice, having good memory locality is very important because it greatly reduces cache misses, which has a large impact on runtime. This is a major advantage of `vector` over `list` in many situations, particularly those where you need to iterate over the entire container more often than you need to add or remove elements.

Answer (score 3):

The memory in a `std::vector` is required to be contiguous, so it's typically represented as an array.

Your question about the complexity of the operations on a `std::vector` is a good one - I remember wondering this myself when I first started programming. If you append an element to a `std::vector`, then it may have to perform a resize operation and copy over all the existing elements to a new array. This will take time O(n) in the worst case. However, the [*amortized* cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis#Dynamic_Array) of appending an element is O(1). By this, we mean that the total cost of *any* sequence of n appends to a `std::vector` is always O(n). The intuition behind this is that the `std::vector` usually overallocates space in its array, leaving a lot of free slots for elements to be inserted into without a reallocation. As a result, most of the appends will take time O(1) even though every now and then you'll have one that takes time O(n).

That said, the cost of performing an insertion elsewhere in a `std::vector` will be O(n), because you may have to shift everything down.

You also asked why this is, if it defeats the purpose of having a dynamic array. Even if the `std::vector` just acted like a managed array, it's still a win over raw arrays. The `std::vector` knows its size, can do bounds-checking (with `at`), is an actual object (unlike an array), and doesn't decay to a pointer. These extra features - coupled with the extra logic to make appends work quickly - are almost always worth it.